# Show more information about ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.10, django-reversion

I use [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) app in my project.

I have modal **"Task"** with **ManyToMany field "comments"**. In my project I have page with revertions list. And it shows me in comments field id of comments. *For example*: comments (field_name): [66, 67, 68] (field_value).

What the best way to take that id-s and show the comment information (author, text, created) not only id. Is it possible? I am little bit comfused.

**models.py:**

```
@reversion.register()
class Task(models.Model):
    comments = models.ManyToManyField("Comment")

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views.py:**

```
def task_reversions(request, project_code, task_code):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_code, status='open')
    task = get_object_or_404(GroupTask, pk=group_task_code)
    versions = Version.objects.get_for_object(ask)
    context = {
        'project': project,
        'task': task,
        'versions': versions,
    }
    return render(request, 'project/task_reversions.html', context)
```

**task_reversions.html:**

```
{% for field_name, field_value in version.field_dict.items %}
     {{ field_name }}
     {{ field_value }}
{% endfor %}
```